# Symfony Form EntityType doesn't select the current value on render by default

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I stumbled upon an odd behavior and I'm still not sure if my solution is the most appropriate one, even though it works now.

I have 2 entities:

```php
class Recipe
{
    /** [...] */
    public $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) */
    public $name;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Location") */
    public $location;
}

class Location
{
    /** [...] */
    public $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) */
    public $name;

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Recipe", mappedBy="location") */
    protected $recipes;
}
```

Nothing fancy here. A location can hold several recipes, and a recipe can be in one location at most.

The recipe form is built as follows:

```php
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'name',
                TextType::class,
                ['label' => 'Name',]
            )
            ->add(
                'location',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Location',
                    'class' => \App\Entity\Location::class,
                    'choice_value' => function ($location) {
                        // Why is this code necessary?
                        return is_object($location)
                            ? $location->getId()    // Object passed (when building choices)
                            : $location;            // int value passed (when checking for selection)
                    },
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                ]
            )
        ;
    }
```

Then the controller creates the form and so on.

```php
    /**
     * @ParamConverter("entity", class="App:Recipe", isOptional="true")
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, object $entity = null) {
        $form = $this->createForm(\App\Form\Recipe::class, $entity ?? new Recipe());
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
```

My original implementation didn't have the `choice_value` callback above on the `EntityType` form element, and the option was never selected when I opened an existing location. But apart from that, everything was working as expected and selecting a value *did* save it correctly in the database, without more code but Symfony's magic.

Could you tell me why this `choice_value` is necessary here? Did I miss something?
Why is the value passed as argument is sometimes an object, and sometimes an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... Found it. Actually I had an old `DataTransformer` that was associated to this field and it was messing with the values. I didn't need it anymore anyway so just removing it magically fixed the bug.

Thanks for your help anyway, it did confirm that something wasn't right and forced me to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the cause of the problem, but for `EntityType` field, you don't need to manually set the `choice_value`.

From [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-value):

> In the EntityType, this is overridden to use the id by default. When the id is used, Doctrine only queries for the objects for the ids that were actually submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it's not necessary.. Maybe because your relation between entities is uni-directional ?

Example that works:

In entity Level

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Level", inversedBy="steps")
 */
private $level;
```

In entity Step

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Step", mappedBy="level")
 */
private $steps;
```

Then StepType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('level', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'Related level',
            'class' => Level::class,
            'choice_label' => 'position'
        ])
    ;
}
```

Comment: Well, that was my understanding too.
About the uni-directional link, I may have over-simplified my code, because I do have it. I've edited my post accordingly.